# AWS CodeDeploy hangs before ApplicationStop on a Windows server

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy an ASP.NET Core 3.0 sample project to a Windows 2019 server EC2 instance. When I initiate the deployment, it hangs at "In Progress" and each event says, "Pending". After failure, they all say, "Skipped".

Here is my appspec.yml:

```
version: 0.0
os: windows
files:
  - source: \
    destination: c:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

I have the CodeDeploy agent installed on the server as well as the .NET Core hosting bundle. I tried installing into a random folder instead of c:\inetpub\wwwroot without luck. The deployment always times out after 5 minutes with the error message,

> The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances
>   failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for
>   deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are
>   experiencing problems.

I gave the Deployment a role with the AWSCodeDeployRole permission.

Any ideas on what could be going wrong? Best as I can tell, this should be a straight forward copy/paste job for CodeDeploy...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to restart the codedeploy agent, sometimes it "hangs" on 2019

Answer (score 1):

We've run into the same issue. Server 2019 is not on the [supported OS list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent.html#codedeploy-agent-supported-operating-systems) so we used a server 2016 image and it worked.